# Subclass of Generic in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Generic Class in Unity and I want to be able to have an additional variable in it when I use i.e. the type `int`.

My generic class `Grid<int>`:

```
public class Grid<T>
{
    public T[] array;
}
```

I've tried to extend my generic class `Grid<T>` with a class named `Grid<int>` to be able to add the variable there:

```
public class Grid<int> : Grid<T>
{
    string additionalVariable;
}
```

But that throws the error

`The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

How can I achieve that creating a `new Grid<int>` class gives me access to `Grid<int>.additionalVariable`, but i.e. `new Grid<float>` wouldn't?

Comment: you need to pass something for `<T>~

Comment: try changing it to `public class IntGrid : Grid<int>`

Comment: public class Grid<T>
    {
        public T[] array;
    }

    public class NewGrid : Grid<int>
    {

    }

Comment: @TobiasWeger You can't have a property on `Grid<int>` that does not exist for, say, `Grid<double>`. `Grid` is no longer generic at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a concrete class, you should give the class a unique name and define the type parameter in the inheritance definition.

```
public class IntGrid : Grid<int>
{
     // Yourvariablehere
}
```

Comment: Are you sure thats the only possibility? I'd like to just have `Grid<int>` with the access to the variable.

Comment: @TobiasWeger And how would you create an instance of this class? It´s not clear if `Grid<int>` should resolve to your derived or the generic base-class-

Comment: So what I want is not possible?

Comment: Well you can always modify the original class.

Answer (score 1):

When a developer "extends" a class, that actually means they are creating a *new* class that extends the existing one. For example, to add a string variable, you might have this:

```
public class Grid<T>
{
    public T[] array;
}

public class ExtendedGrid<T> : Grid<T>
{
    string additionalVariable;
}

var grid = new Grid<int>();
grid.additionalVariable = "Hello world"; //Error: method does not exist

var extendedGrid = new ExtendedGrid<int>();
extendedGrid.additionaVariable = "Hello world"; //Works
```

When you extend the class, you have the option of leaving the generic type open (as it is above) or closed (as in this following example).

```
public class Grid<T>
{
    public T[] array;
}

public class ExtendedGrid : Grid<int>  
{
    string additionalVariable;
}

var extendedGrid = new ExtendedGrid(); //No need to specify int as the type argument
```

If you don't want to modify the original class, but want to add a member to it, your only option is to add an extension method:

```
static public class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetAdditionalVariable<T>(this Grid<T> source)
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}

var grid = new Grid<int>();
var s = grid.GetAdditionalVariable();
```

Unfortunately there is no such thing as an extension field, so I'm guessing you want one of the first two examples.

Comment: Sadly not what I wanted. Thank you anyway!